# java.io.IOException: Broken pipe on start application and login and logout application

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have an application (JSF 2.0, Hibernate 3.6, Oracle 11g, Glassfish 4.0) that every time I start, login or logout it presents me with these errors:

```
java.io.IOException: Broken Pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    ...



java.io.IOException: Connection closed
at org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.TaskQueue.onClose(TaskQueue.java:298)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.onClose(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:613)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.closeConnection(TCPNIOTransport.java:611)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$2.run(NIOConnection.java:432)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler$RunnableTask.run(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:487)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTaskQueue(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:293)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTasks(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.preSelect(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:100)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:329)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:274)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Despite this error, my application works correctly, does search in the database, authenticates users, etc ...
I have no idea who might be causing this error

Comment: 1 possibility is a database-thrown connection timeout, which you can trap on Exception and reopen the connection automatically when this happens. Another, which will be harder to catch, would be a defective router (if your host is not local). And finally, it's possible that somewhere in your code you are closing the connection yourself.

Comment: Please post the entire stack traces.Edit: including thread names if you have them.

Comment: The "Broken Pipe" exception could be caused by the browser navigating away from a page before the server has finished sending the response. The rest of the stack trace would be useful.

Comment: I put entire exception stack of "connection close" error